# Unable to authenticate application using Twitter OAuth with Spring Security OAuth2 Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, twitter, oauth-2.0

I’m trying to authenticate users from Twitter using Spring Security OAuth2 Client. I have the following configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          twitter:
            client-id: ${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ${BASE_URL}/login/oauth2/code/twitter
            scope:
            - tweet.read
        provider:
          twitter:
            authorization-uri: https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token
```

The `${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}`, `${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}`, and `${BASE_URL}` are all set as environment variables, don’t seem to be having issues with those.

When I click the login button I’m taken to twitter’s login page and I authenticate without issue but afterwards I’m taken to a page with the message:

```
You weren’t able to give access to the App. Go back and try logging in again.
```

Set my redirect URL in Twitter's OAuth2 settings as `https://myapp.com/login/oauth2/code/twitter`

Using the following security dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Please share your solution 

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong just that you need a small update to your properties file because Twitter OAuth 2.0 only supports Authorization Code Flow with PKCE. This was a known issue with the Twitter authorization request URL generated by Spring. For Twitter, they require these two request parameters to come along with the request URL **code_challenge** and **code_challenge_method**.

A sample URL from Twitter developer page looks like

```
https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com&scope=tweet.read%20users.read%20follows.read%20offline.access&state=state&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain
```

In your own case with Spring, in the properties file (your YAML file), update the **authorization-URI** under the provider for twitter to append those two parameters **`code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain`** to look like this

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          twitter:
            client-id: ${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${TWITTER_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ${BASE_URL}/login/oauth2/code/twitter
            scope:
            - tweet.read
        provider:
          twitter:
            authorization-uri: https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain
            token-uri: https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token
```

ALTERNATIVE:
***This requires Spring Boot 2.7 and above.***

Instantiate a bean of ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver

```
@Bean
public ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver auth2RequestWithPKCE(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo) {
  var resolver = new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo); 
  resolver .setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());

  return resolver;
}
```

Then in the security config, inject the above bean and add it to the oauth2Login http security config settings as follows

```
http
  *** //other settings
  .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.authorizationRequestResolver(INJECTED_BEAN_HERE));
```

Note, your redirect_uri needs to match whatever you put on the Twitter developer settings page. For development purposes, don't use localhost for the redirect_uri, use 127.0.0.1 instead on the Twitter developer settings page and your yaml redirect_uri.

Hope this help